# Retrieve API's response content types in OperationFilter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swashbuckle

For example, consider an API with :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.OperationFilter<CustomFilter>());

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public void Get() { }
}
```

This API can return response with the content type `application/json` and `application/xml`.

I want create a custom `OperationFilter` to generate OpenApi response with API's content type possibilities :

```cs
public class Foo { }

public class CustomFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(Foo), context.SchemaRepository);
        operation.Responses.Clear();
        var response = new OpenApiResponse();
        var apiResponseTypes = new[] { "application/json", "application/xml" }; // <- How get this from API metadata? 
        foreach(string responseType in apiResponseTypes)
        {
            response.Content.Add(responseType, new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema });
        }
        operation.Responses.Add("200", response);
    }
}
```

How retrieve the API response content types in OperationFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only MVC controller can return XML content type (minimal API can return only json). `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` impact `MvcOptions`, so it's where to search.

To get response application type, you can :

```cs
MvcOptions mvc = ...; // Injected from service provider
var apiResponseTypes = new List<string>();
var jsonApplicationType = _mvc.Value.FormatterMappings.GetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json");
if(jsonApplicationType != null)
    apiResponseTypes.Add(jsonApplicationType);
var xmlApplicationType = _mvc.Value.FormatterMappings.GetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml");
if (xmlApplicationType != null)
    apiResponseTypes.Add(xmlApplicationType);
}
```

This solution isn't perfect, because it's only manage xml/json. Custom media type isn't taken into account.

---

In operation filter, it's :

```cs
public class CustomFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly IOptions<MvcOptions> _mvc;

    public CustomFilter(IOptions<MvcOptions> mvc)
    {
        _mvc = mvc;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(Foo), context.SchemaRepository);
        operation.Responses.Clear();
        var response = new OpenApiResponse();

        var apiResponseTypes = new List<string>();
        //If no MVC (generaly minimal API)
        if(_mvc.Value == null)
        {
            apiResponseTypes.Add("application/json");
        }
        else
        {
            var jsonApplicationType = _mvc.Value.FormatterMappings.GetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("json");
            if(jsonApplicationType != null)
                apiResponseTypes.Add(jsonApplicationType);
            var xmlApplicationType = _mvc.Value.FormatterMappings.GetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml");
            if (xmlApplicationType != null)
                apiResponseTypes.Add(xmlApplicationType);
        }
        
        foreach (string responseType in apiResponseTypes)
        {
            response.Content.Add(responseType, new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema });
        }
        operation.Responses.Add("200", response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use other action attribute(such as `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute),you may try with

```
context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes.First()?.ApiResponseFormats.Select(x=>x.MediaType).ToArray();
```

the filter:

```
 public class CustomFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(typeof(Foo), context.SchemaRepository);
            operation.Responses.Clear();
            var response = new OpenApiResponse();
            
            var apiResponseTypes = context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes.First()?.ApiResponseFormats.Select(x=>x.MediaType).ToArray();
            //var apiResponseTypes = new[] { "application/json", "application/xml" }; // <- How get this from API metadata? 
            foreach (string responseType in apiResponseTypes)
            {
                response.Content.Add(responseType, new OpenApiMediaType { Schema = schema });
            }
            operation.Responses.Add("200", response);
        }
    }
```

Notice :

if your action is  void method,ApiResponseFormats  would be null

if your action return  `Foo/Foo[]` , ApiResponseFormats would contain

```
application/json
text/json
text/plain
```

by default

Comment: `context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes` is empty on action that return `void`.

Comment: I've metioned it in my answer,since it retrun void,it won't have response body,so it won't have content-type either .However,the allowed content-type for different endpoint shouldn't alway be the same

Comment: Also,in your question,there's an apicontroller in your project,it's not a minimal api project, you could call builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); for endpoints in controller

Comment: Sorry. In my question I put a minimal API endpoint... Minimal API endpoint support only json, then the question lose interest. So I edited to add controller endpoint.